# Tensorflow can't work on Zeppelin

Tags: tensorflow

I want to run tensorflow on Zeppelin:System Ubuntu 16.04,python2.7. 
First,I directly pip install tensorflow on system  and download zeppelin
binary from the website. When I test the tensorflow from the system commandline it's ok. But when I start Zeppelin and use the Zeppelin from
another pc get errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
ImportError: cannot import name pywrap_tensorflow
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

I search the web and think this error may caused by the Pip install. So I download the source and compile the tensorflow. It's still the same error.

But when I use the jupyter notebook. It's OK!
So I ask for help
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're running the script in the installation directory. [This is a common issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3217) with Tensorflow.

Comment: I think I didn't run the Zeppelin in the Tensorflow directory.  The Zeppelin is a separate directory in my computer.  I use another PC through the web wo access the Zeppelin . So i think not this problem. Thanks.